# 3SAT satisfiable so bipartite graph is Hamiltonian in polynomial time

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, computer-science, computational-complexity, satisfiability

I failed a graph theory exam last week and I would like to know how to solve some of the problems I got because I don't have any idea. One of the problems is:

> Prove that, if for every instance of 3SAT problem we can decide in polynomial time complexity if it is satisfiable, then, for every bipartite graph we can decide in polynomial time complexity if it is Hamiltonian.

I don't even know how to start it. Could you help me with a proof for that, please?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term $\text{NP-Problem}$?

Comment: Yes, I am. And I know what is 3SAT but I am bad at making proofs.

Comment: My point is the reduction from SAT or 3SAT to Hamiltonian-Path, is more of computational complexity question, and less of graph theory question. For those kind of proofs (some how technical with a lot of details) I recommend check Sipser book.